# Bridge Movie Night - Winter Holiday Edition

Tags: discussion, community-event

Since Yuuki is currently a student near the end of a school term he's far too busy to have time to eat, let alone make a meta for movie night, so I'm making the meta for him this month. You may call me Wipuki, and this is the WINTER HOLIDAY SPECIAL MOVIE NIGHT WIPUKI THEMED HOLIDAY EDITION OF BRIDGE MOVIE NIGHT (FEATURING WIPUKI AS YUUKI), so suggest your favourite winter holiday movies for us to watch. As usual, make sure your movie is available to rent or purchase online, or we won't be able to watch it.

This month the showings will be on December 19th & 20th at 10PM UTC.

Comment: SMDH if you're gonna show a Christmas movie that isn't Die Hard.

Comment: Dammit, I'm not gonna make it at 10PM.

Answer (score 17):

## DIE HARD

Did you know that *Die Hard* was the first "Christmas" movie?

[image]

> Now I have a machine gun
> Ho Ho Ho

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 92%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/die_hard/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qxBXm7ZUTM)

Comment: I've never actually watched Die Hard.

Comment: @Wipqozn - Wow.

Comment: I feel bad for upvoting fredley, but this is one hell of a movie.

Comment: I'm with @Wipqozn, I've never actually seen this movie either. I like how these movie nights are catching me up on stuff everyone but me seems to have seen.

Comment: -1 As I've said for other movie nights, I don't think R rated movies are the most appropriate for community movie nights. The point of these in my mind is really to allow anyone that wants to to join in and enjoy a movie with our community. Not saying everyone needs to want to watch every movie we show, but I'm just not sure this sort of thing is appropriate for this kind of event.

Comment: @Ktash 1988 R != 2015 R.

Comment: Am half tempted to roll back the edit, not gunna lie

Comment: 1988? This movie is older than I am!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz The movie contains excessive swearing, lots of violence, and a few (brief) scenes showing naked women. Yes, the ratings system has changed (though I think it was more lenient in the 80s, imo), but the content of the movie is still objectionable and it is still rated R. My down vote and opinion stand. Not that every R rated movie would fall into that category, nor will a movie need be R to be inappropriate for a community movie night.

Comment: @ktash From that description, the Bridge itself is probably R rated anyway.

Comment: Looks like I'll finally get to wtch Die Hard.

Comment: Umm... I see it on TV every other day :/

Answer (score 8):

### Movie Suggestion: Home Alone

[image]

A classic Christmas movie about a kid who is forgotten at home while the rest of his family goes on vacation.  Hi-jinks ensue.

Comment: image broken on my end. Is it on i.imgur? i.imgur is banned in turkey while i.stack.imgur isn't. edit: nope i.stack got banned too apparently.

Comment: No, I was direct linking to the IMDb image, which wasn't cooperating.

Comment: Oh I see. Nice to see that they didn't ban this, yet.

Answer (score 3):

### Movie Suggestion: <s>Yuuki</s> Wipqozn Plays Undertale Blind And Cries Like A Damn Baby

[image]

[IMDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWVI0.png) | [Rotten Tomatoes 110%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbE6t.png) | [Trailer](https://i.imgur.com/WjEk6M8.jpg)

Comment: That reminds me, I really need to play this game.

Comment: @Wipqozn You really do.

Comment: Since we have Wipuki this month, who will be playing it and crying like a baby? Wipqozn or Yuuki?

Comment: @Unionhawk Both?

Comment: The only thing with this is it'd end up being way longer than a movie, unless Yuuki/Wipqozn turn out to be speedrun gods immediately

Comment: tenouttaten, tenouttaten hundredouttahundred, best game, BEST GAME

Comment: @Wipqozn now you can play while crying and us watching :)

Comment: Oh wait, no, I stand corrected. It's only got a 142 minute running time, per IMDB.

Comment: @uni That's Yuuki, not Wipqozn.

Comment: I love that there are 10+ upvotes on this

Comment: I hate to ruin it, but the IMDB is based on [The Shawshank Redemption](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/). /r/ididthemath

Answer (score 3):

### Movie Suggestion: Elf

[image]

A Christmas comedy special starring Will Ferrell. Description courtesy of google:

> Buddy (Will Ferrell) was accidentally transported to the North Pole as a toddler and raised to adulthood among Santa's elves. Unable to shake the feeling that he doesn't fit in, the adult Buddy travels to New York, in full elf uniform, in search of his real father. As it happens, this is Walter Hobbs (James Caan), a cynical businessman. After a DNA test proves this, Walter reluctantly attempts to start a relationship with the childlike Buddy with increasingly chaotic results.

[Rotten Tomatoes (84%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/elf/) | [IMBD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0319343/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gW9wRNqQ_P8)

Answer (score -1):

**Movie Suggestion: Someone plays SNATCHER while I yell at you.**

[image]

SNATCHER is Blade Runner but by incredible genius Hideo Kojima, known for the Metal Gear Solid series. It's also a Christmas game! I know a lot about this game and will yell at you while you play it, maybe even make fun of you for not solving the puzzles. Alcohol might be involved.

Comment: Fine! I'll have my own SNATCHER Christmas celebration. We'll have booze, SNATCHER, yelling, and some sobbing for good measure. You know what? Forget SNATCHER!

Answer (score -2):

#### Movie Suggestion: The Santa Clause

[image: Movie Cover]

I haven't seen this movie since I was a kid, but it was pretty enjoyable from what I remember. The plot of the movie is that Tim Allen accidentally kills Santa Clause, which result in him becoming the new Santa Clause and then hijinks and life lessons happen.

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111070/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 75%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/santa_clause/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t067u2Jnks0)

Answer (score -2):

**MOVIE SUGGESTION: Year Without a Santa Claus**

[image]

*When a weary and discouraged Santa Claus considers skipping his Christmas Eve run one year, Mrs. Claus and his Elves set out to change his mind.*

Now this movie is a classic, there's not much else I can say about it. It is a musical, which may bother some people, but the songs are pretty freakin catchy, especially the Miser Brothers.

It is relatively short at only around 50 Minutes, so another showing from this style of movie could be added (like [Santa Claus is Coming to Town](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066327/?ref_=tt_rec_tti) to make up extra time)

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072424/?ref_=ttmd_md_nm) | [Rotten Tomatoes: 83%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/year_without_a_santa_claus_1974/)

Comment: One of the best of the Rankin/Bass classics.  We watch this every year in my family!

Answer (score -2):

#### Movie Suggestion: Krull

[image: Movie Cover]

[IMBD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 33%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/krull/) | [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndpV6qfQJVw)

> A prince and a fellowship of companions set out to rescue his bride from a fortress of alien invaders who have arrived on their home planet.

Answer (score -5):

#### Movie Suggestion: The Wiz

[image: Movie Cover]

[IMBD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078504/) | [Rotten Tomatoes 30%](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/wiz/) | [Trailer](http://www.imdb.com/video/screenplay/vi2130051353?ref_=tt_pv_vi_aiv_2)

> Dorothy, a twenty-four-year-old kindergarten teacher born, raised, and still working in Harlem, is celebrating Thanksgiving with her extended family, but she doesn't seem to be thankful for much in life. She lives a self-imposed sheltered life; she is shy and unfulfilled. Things change for her when she is caught in a snowstorm while chasing after her dog, Toto. They are transported to the mysterious Land of Oz, where she is informed that the only possible way to find her way back home is through the assistance of the powerful wizard in the Emerald City. As she goes searching for him, she befriends some creatures who are facing problems in life just like her. In their quest to find and get help from the wizard, they also face Evillene, the equally evil sister of Evermean, the wicked witch whom Dorothy inadvertently killed when she arrived in Oz, and who may be their biggest obstacle in achieving their goals.